# In SQL (SQLite) I have a column of pupil names and their birthdays - How do I show the oldest 5 pupils?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQL (SQLite) I have a column of names and their birthdays - How do I show the oldest 5 people?

In a separate command how can I use the birthdays and group them by age:

```
21-30
31-40
41-50
51+
```

Many Thanks

Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display oldest 5 people

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
ORDER BY birth_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

To group birthdates , I have used answer from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123951/sqlite-how-to-calculate-age-from-birth-date) to calculate age

```
SELECT person_name,
       CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
            WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
            WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
            WHEN age >=51 THEN '51+' END as Age_Group
FROM
(
   SELECT person_name,
       (strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', Birth_Date)) - (strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', Birth_Date));
   FROM tableName as age

) As Z
```

To find number of birthdates belonging to each birth group

```
SELECT Age_Group , COUNT(*) as countAgeGroup
FROM (
       SELECT 
           CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
                WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
                WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
                WHEN age >=51 THEN '51+' END as Age_Group
       FROM
       (
          SELECT 
             (strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', Birth_Date)) - (strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', Birth_Date));
          FROM tableName as age

       ) As Z  
   ) As Y
  GROUP BY Y.Age_Group
```