# No such column though table has that column

Tags: sqlite

This is my table:

```
/* Column information for - tblPersonalInfo */
----------------------------------------------

cid      name             type        notnull      dflt_value      pk   
------- --------------- ---------- ----------- -------------- --- 
0        userID           INTEGER     0                            1    
1        firstName        TEXT        0                            0    
2        middleName       TEXT        0                            0    
3        lastName         TEXT        0                            0    
4        nameSuffix       TEXT        0                            0    
5        birthday         DATE        0                            0    
6        sex              INTEGER     0                            0    
7        height_foot      INTEGER     0                            0    
8        height_inch      INTEGER     0                            0    
9        weight           REAL        0                            0    
10       civilStatus      INTEGER     0                            0    
11       contactNo        TEXT        0                            0    
12       emailAddress     TEXT        0                            0    
13       address_city     TEXT        0                            0    
14       address_brgy     TEXT        0                            0    
15       photo            BLOB        0                            0
```

I want to execute this query to get the **Age** of an Employee in tblPersonalInfo table:

```
SELECT CAST(STRFTIME('%Y.%m%d', 'NOW') - STRFTIME('%Y.%m%d', birthday) AS INT) AS Age
FROM tblPersonalInfo
```

I emulate that query/formula from [SQLite: How to calculate age from birth date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123951/sqlite-how-to-calculate-age-from-birth-date) but SQLite gives me an error message that says:

> > Error: No such column: birthday

Advanced thanks to our experts here in StackOverflow community.

Comment: wel.... er... humm... the problem is that... the column "birthday" does not exists. Hence "no such column"

Comment: lol, I almost say the same, but the table he shows is the table info, the actual column is in row five with cid 5...

Comment: @Roberto darn.. now I feel dumb. Although, the error message is quite clear on this.. ummm.... it works fine in SQLFiddle,

Comment: @wennie check again your table definition, it works fine in SQLfiddle =/ check it out:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3fb82/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found out that the problem was the stored data in the table (**birthday** column).

I stored it as a **String** instead of **Date** data type through Delphi as follows (notice the Parameter Data Type in sqSavePersonalInfo):

```
{TSQLQuery.SQL.Text}

UPDATE tblPersonalInfo
SET
    firstName = :prmFirstName,
    middleName = :prmMiddlenName,
    lastName = :prmLastName,
    nameSuffix = :prmNameSuffix,
    birthday = :prmBirthday,
    sex = :prmSex,
    height_foot = :prmFoot,
    height_inch = :prmInch,
    weight = :prmWeight,
    civilStatus = :prmCivilStatus,
    contactNo = :prmContactNo,
    emailAddress = :prmEmailAddress,
    address_city = :prmAddressCity,
    address_brgy = :prmVillage
WHERE
    userID = :prmUserID;
```

---

```
{Setting the parameters value, specifically the birthday parameter}
...    
sqSavePersonalInfo.ParamByName('prmBirthday').AsString := FormatDateTime('YYYY/MM/DD', dtpDateOfBirth.Date);
...
```

I test to insert some data again in **birthday** field. This time, not a String datatype.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2c09e/3

Anyway, Mr.Ricardo's comment helped me to find ways to correct this kind of problem.